# Eclipse uses old PATH variable to execute command line process in Gradle Task?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, groovy, gradle

I use Gradle [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) task. It executes a command line process. The command I want to execute is:

```
pod install
```

It requires [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) to be installed. I did that. I check that it works from the command line by using `pod --version`. The output is the latest version, which is 0.37.2. My system is OS X and I use the latest Eclipse Luna version.

I created a custom Gradle Task:

```
class InstallPodTask extends DefaultTask {

      @InputDirectory File srcDir

      @TaskAction
      def pod() {

        def xcodeProjectDir = // the dir the pod command is executed in

        try {
           project.exec {
              workingDir xcodeProjectDir
              executable "pod"
              args "install"
           }   
        } catch (Exception exception) { 

        }

     }
}
```

When I use this task from the command line it works without any problems.

The problem occurs when the task is executed inside Eclipse. I use the gradle plugin for eclipse. I got the following error when running the above task from eclipse:

CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

```
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[0m
[!] Unable to load a specification for the plugin `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-0.4.1`
[!] Unable to load a specification for the plugin `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-try-0.4.3`
[!] Unable to load a specification for the plugin `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-0.6.0`
[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (0.37.2) is higher than the version of the current executable (0.36.0). Incompatibility issues may arise.
Analyzing dependencies
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:119:in ``': No such file or directory - git (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:119:in `git_information'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:38:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:59:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:374:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:315:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:303:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.0/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':j2objcXcode'.
> Process 'command 'pod'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.91 secs
[sts] Build failed
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:71)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.TaskUtil.execute(TaskUtil.java:117)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.launch.GradleProcess$1.doit(GradleProcess.java:92)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable$1.run(GradleRunnable.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':j2objcXcode'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':j2objcXcode'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'pod'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.exec(DefaultFileOperations.java:154)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.exec(AbstractProject.java:787)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.exec(AbstractProject.java:783)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$exec$4.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.j2objccontrib.j2objcgradle.tasks.J2objcXcodeTask.pod(J2objcXcodeTask.groovy:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 57 more
[sts] Time taken: 0 min, 5 sec
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
```

The error says that:

> The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (0.37.2) is higher than the version of the current executable (0.36.0).

This is strange when I run `pod --version` from the terminal I get version `0.37.2` as a result.

**Why does the task running inside eclipse behaves different than when running from terminal? Does eclipse use a different command line?**

Comment: Probably it does, or maybe has *stale* PATH?

Comment: @Opal What do you mean by stale Path?

Comment: I meant that eclipse *PATH* is not synchronized with system PATH, thus and older version is displayed.

Comment: @Opal How do I update eclipse path?

Comment: No idea, IntelliJ user.

Comment: I am not a user of Gradle or CocoaPods. But I guess Gradle(eclipse plugin ) internally use some kind of plugins to use CocoaPods , and that internal CocoaPods plugin's version is mismatching.You can take a look at [gradle-cocoapods-plugin/releases](https://github.com/x2on/gradle-cocoapods-plugin/releases)

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart Eclipse after changing any system environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the  **lockfile** from pod installation (**which was created when you run it from command prompt** ), then **run again using eclipse**. **lockfile genereted by the command line process used CocoaPods (0.37.2) while eclipse using  CocoaPods (0.36.0)** plugins to install pod. Please revart if you need any more information.

EDIT :: use **rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace** before run **pod install**